# SyncAdapter process killed when app process is terminated

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

Why the SyncAdapter process (:sync) is killed when the app is swiped from the app switcher list ? i thought the whole intention here is to keep them decoupled.

**EDIT:**

Following is the code used. `mUploadTask` is a `AsyncTask` im executing that reads information from a sqlite table (using `getContext().getContentResolver()`) and uploads relevant data to a backend (using `HttpPost`). Very straight forward.

Also, i implemented only one `onSyncCanceled()` since my `SyncAdapter` doesnt support syncing of multiple accounts in parallel.

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter implements UploadTaskListener {

private static final String TAG = SyncAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private static volatile UploadTask mUploadTask;

/**
 * Set up the sync adapter
 */
public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
}

/**
 * Set up the sync adapter. This form of the
 * constructor maintains compatibility with Android 3.0
 * and later platform versions
 */
public SyncAdapter(
        Context context,
        boolean autoInitialize,
        boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
    super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
        ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

    MHLog.logI(TAG, "onPerformSync");

    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);

    if (mUploadTask == null) {
        synchronized (SyncAdapter.class) {
            if (mUploadTask == null) {
                mUploadTask = new UploadTask(getContext(), this).executeOnSettingsExecutor();
                MHLog.logI(TAG, "onPerformSync - running");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSyncCanceled() {
    MHLog.logI(TAG, "onSyncCanceled");
    if(mUploadTask != null){
        mUploadTask.cancel(true);
        mUploadTask = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your UploadTask is this just an AsyncTask?

Comment: @AsafK First of all where is an account creation, etc? Look at the docs example. Second, why do you need async task if onPerformSync itself runs in the worker thread?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> Syncs can be cancelled at any time by the framework. For example a sync that was not user-initiated and lasts longer than 30 minutes will be considered timed-out and cancelled. Similarly the framework will attempt to determine whether or not an adapter is making progress by monitoring its network activity over the course of a minute. If the network traffic over this window is close enough to zero the sync will be cancelled. You can also request the sync be cancelled via `cancelSync(Account, String)` or `cancelSync(SyncRequest)`.
>
> A sync is cancelled by issuing a `interrupt()` on the syncing thread. Either your code in `onPerformSync(Account, Bundle, String, ContentProviderClient, SyncResult)` must check `interrupted()`, or you you must override one of `onSyncCanceled(Thread)`/`onSyncCanceled()` (depending on whether or not your adapter supports syncing of multiple accounts in parallel). If your adapter does not respect the cancel issued by the framework you run the risk of your app's entire process being killed.

Are you making sure your honoring the rules of the SyncAdapter framework?

Additionally, it would be nice to see some of your code to drill down to why the framework is cancelling your Sync...

Comment: See my updated question. As you can see i do honor the rules. Also, the work done by the SyncAdapter takes much less than 30 minutes and basically consists of uploading data over the network. Not sure what im doing wrong here.

Comment: What means "[...] a sync that was not user-initiated and lasts longer than 30 minutes [...]"? Exists some way to determine when user initiated this process? In our case, is the user who initiated this... How to notify Android about this? 
Our process is internal, we don't use internet connecton, only synck contacts with phone adresses book. And sometimes, Android Framework kills the process if it takes more than 30 or 45 minutes. Rarely, but it occours,  allow us to finish without problems even with 60 minutes of delay...

Answer (score 2):

The **onPerformSync()** works on a separate thread. So, you don't need to create any executor variables to implement the background work.

I had the same problem - my adapter has been using executor in onPerformSync() method, that perform operations (now - the one more thread).
That's a **reason** - in case the system doesn't see any job in onPerformSync() method in it's thread (because you've created executor that perform actions in another thread) - the **onSyncCanceled()** method will be invoked - it is just a question of time.

The short time operations will be done, but the long time (10 min) will be terminated by **onSyncCanceled()**.

You can override **onSyncCanceled()** in your adapter - but you should understand the real problem and avoid it.

Here is the project sample https://github.com/Udinic/SyncAdapter. Do the client-server implementation in onPerformSync() method and have no problem.