# Android SyncAdapter causing InterruptedException

Tags: android, retrofit, coroutine

I have a SyncAdapter that makes requests using retrofit inside coroutines async. The problem is that for some reason the syncAdapter gets canceled and this also cancels my request causing InterruptedException.
Anyone can tell me what I`m doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You should show people your code. Otherwise they won't be able to help you

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042274/syncadapter-process-killed-when-app-process-is-terminated) may help.

Comment: Just guessing here. The docs of the AbstractSyncAdapter point out that the framework will monitor network traffic to determine if the sync process is making progess. Probably if the network requests from Retrofit are on another thread/dispatcher then they might not be detected by the framework and an interrupt exception is thrown. (As I said I am only guessing)